# Will type casting to large to small data types cause data loss in C?

Tags: c

I eager to know, how big storage data or pointers casted to small, without 
loosing their, ?

Ex : For simplicity, I am giving this example, but I would try with Big
Structure pointers (structure have more members) to small

`int` to store in `char`, `double` to `int`.

Comment: you comedy guy :), it also applicable to C++  thats why i added, silly question ...........

Comment: There are missing words in your question, and the example you mention is missing too. So please [edit] your question and be more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear.

Of course converting a value from one type to one with fewer bits available will lose the bits that don't fit, so if they're being used they will be lost. Where would it otherwise go?

For pointers the question is even less clear, the size of the pointed-at object does not affect the size of the pointer, in general.

Given:

```
struct small { int a; };
struct big { int b[1000]; };
```

it does *not* follow that `sizeof (struct small *)` is smaller than `sizeof (struct big *)`, and on many typical modern systems they will be the exact same size.

Comment: "converting a value from one type to one with fewer bits available will lose data"  depends on the value.  `(char) 1` does not lose information.  `(int) 1.2` will lose info.

Comment: @chux Good point, I've edited to try and make the reasoning clearer. Thanks.

Comment: Aside: Determining, in a portable way, if a `float` value will convert to a `long` without losing info is not a trivial problem given potential UB of 6.3.1.4.  OP might be asking something along those lines, but post is unclear.